# scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval is not calling at correct intervals sometimes

Tags: ios

I have two separate timers on for recording data at 0.25 seconds and other for recording location details at 1 sec as below

```
 self.hardBrakingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];

self.locationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(locationTimerFired:) 
                                                   userInfo:nil 
                                                    repeats:YES];
```

But sometimes these timers are not calling at given time intervals.

Comment: Do you mean that the timer doesn't fire up the selector?

Comment: how are you firing them?

Comment: timer fire up the selector, it's firing with 0.25 second interval correctly for some time but after that the selector is not firing at correct time interval i.e. with 1 second interval or 2 seconds interval it is calling

Comment: Yes, they aren't designed to fire at an exact time period.

Comment: I have these timers running and also some other tasks will run on background. Is there any way that these background tasks affecting my timers and how can I make the timers run with the proper interval independent of any other background tasks and also even when application is in background.

Comment: Might be because of the new timer coalescing features in iOS. In short, the OS synchronizes timers so they all fire up at the same time, to save battery power.

Comment: Will the timers interval gets affect by background tasks running.

Answer (score 1):

You are scheduling a timer in a run loop in the default mode. A Run Loop is basically a *queue*, scheduling tasks on a certain thread. The exact execution time of your timer depends whether there are already other tasks executing in the same run loop.

It's also possible, that another run loop runs "on top" or modifies the "mode" such that other "tasks" are deferred (e.g a user scrolls). You can read more about run loops and "modes" and their surprising behavior in the official documentation: [Anatomy of a Run Loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

You are also likely not getting a *precise* timer with NSTimer anyway, since - as already pointed out by @Cyrille - there is that "Timer coalescing" feature of iOS and OSX: [Timer Coalescing](http://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/). You can however implement a quite precise timer using dispatch lib, see a code sample of mine: [RXTimer](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/8550768)