# Issue with timer

Tags: ios

I have a driving application when I start the trip I have to collect location details along with date and time in hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds for every second and accelerometer details along with date and time in hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds for every 0.25 seconds and when the trip is stopped recording should be stopped. I have taken a timer for location details  with interval 1 second

```
  self.locationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                                     target:self 
                                                   selector:@selector(locationTimerFired:) 
                                                   userInfo:nil 
                                                    repeats:YES];

- (void) locationTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
  { 
       CLLocation *newLocation = locationManager.location;

      [self updateLocation:newLocation andSpeed:newLocation.speed];
      [defaultCenter postNotificationName:LocationChangedNotification 
                                                        object:nil 
                                                      userInfo: userInfo];


 }
```

in the received LocationChangedNotification  I am recording the location and time as mentioned for every second.

This is sometime fine when the application is in foreground but when the application is in background timer timer fires interval is not accurate it fires sometimes for 2 seconds, for 3 seconds and some times 2 times a second why this is happening?
Please suggest. Also I have registered for location updates in background mode in info.plist.

I have taken a timer for accelerometer details  with interval 0.25 second as follows

```
  self.accelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279771/scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-is-not-calling-at-correct-intervals-sometimes

Comment: Maybe it is better to rely on significant movement in background rather than timer. Is it really needed to fire timer every second at the same geographical point?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use timers. Instead, configure the location manager to give you callbacks at your desired accuracy (presumably maximum) and use the callback to save the location and speed with the current time.

Then, when you come to use / display the data you can filter / extrapolate to get the location data at your desired time interval.

The timers don't work in the background because they aren't designed to. Location callbacks are designed to...